# ffmpeg: adding subtitles (.srt) to MKV only adds first subtitle frame

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, matroska

I am trying to add a [separate .srt file](https://file.io/WeMMFp0DfKWT) to an existing MKV container using ffmpeg:

```
> ffmpeg -i 'input.mkv' -fix_sub_duration -i 'subtitles.srt' -map 0 -c copy -map 1 -c:s:1 srt 'output.mkv'
```

I am using `-c:s:1` because the original MKV already has a PSG subtitle stream.

But the resulting MKV container only contains the first subtitle entry:

```
> ffmpeg -i output.mkv -c:s:1 copy output.srt; cat output.txt

1
00:00:06,080 --> 00:00:12,154
Advertise your product or brand here
contact www.OpenSubtitles.org today

> ffprobe output.mkv
[...]
    Stream #0:5(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.54.100 srt
      DURATION        : 00:00:12.154000000
```

Note that the subtitle stream duration is only 12 seconds.

But when I specifically select only the first video stream (`-map 0:v:0`), it works:

```
ffmpeg -i 'input.mkv' -i 'subtitles.srt' -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c copy -map 1 -c:s:1 srt  'output.mkv'
```

I noticed today that the original file contains 2 video streams: the movie (#0:0) and the poster picture (#0:4):

```
> ffprobe input.mkv
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x800, SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, 7.1, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (default)
    Stream #0:4: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x360 [SAR 96:96 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
```

I suspect using `-map 0` causes the extra subtitle stream to be attached to the picture video stream (instead of the main video stream), causing it to only have 1 frame (the first subtitle entry).

How can I avoid this and have extra subtitle(s) be attached to the main video stream, without having to remove the poster picture?

Comment: Can you provide a link to `subtitles.srt`?

Comment: Yes, [here it is](https://file.io/WeMMFp0DfKWT).

Comment: "The file you requested has been deleted". Looks like I was too slow.

Comment: Strange, I thought it had a 2 week lifetime. Anyway, the content of the .srt file is not important. I managed to add them succesfully, but only when I remove the "poster picture"/thumbail. I updated the question.